# Git on MacOS case sensitivity: cannot lock ref

Tags: git, macos, case-sensitive

I believe a teammate had a feature branch named `Fix/my-fix` and then renamed it `fix/my-fix`, changing the case, and pushed it to our central repo.

Now, every time I do a `git pull`, I see

```
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/fix/my-fix': is at addd9e22effc39t86eca875a1db74f4cc2d09747 but expected cec2dce30eb3a5tf370c3d3b39540f9d2e347020
 ! cec2dce30..addd9e22e  fix/my-fix                 -> origin/fix/my-fix  (unable to update local ref)
```

If I do a `git remote prune origin` or `git fetch --all --prune`, then it fixes the issue so I can do **one successful pull** but then the second time I pull I get the error again. So essentially I have to `prune` before every pull.

Is there any way I can solve this issue locally, without deleting his feature branches from our central git repo? I don't care about his branch at all, so an acceptable workaround would be to tell git to ignore it permanently somehow; I just need to be able to consistently `pull` without having to `prune`.

I've also tried

```
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/fix/my-fix
```

and

```
git gc --prune=now
```

and those similarly only solved the issue temporarily.

I've read the background around case-sensitive filesystems in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/case-sensitivity?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts).

Comment: Are both refs still on the server, or is just the one present? You can use `git ls-remote` to check if you're not sure.

Comment: No, only the new lowercase one `addd9e22e` is shown by that command.

Comment: Do you have a branch simply named `fix`?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen i don’t think so. the naming convention people use is to include a slash in their branch names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, the uppercase spelling version of the branch *should not* be returning (so that the one-time `git fetch -p` or `git remote prune` should have been a permanent solution).  However, if it works once, you can just enable it as the *default* action for this one repository on your Mac:

```
git config fetch.prune true
```

or for *all* of your repositories<sup>1</sup> on your Mac:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```

This is equivalent to making all `git fetch` commands be `git fetch -p` commands.

(There's no particularly good reason *not* to run with `fetch.prune` set to `true`.  I do this myself: I have my global configuration set this way.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, this would be all repositories *except* any that locally override with `fetch.prune=false`.  In general—there are some specific and important exceptions—things that you set with `git config --global` get overridden by anything you set with `git config`, because what Git does is:

- Read the system configuration file first, to get settings.
- Read your global configuration file for settings.  Anything you set here that was already set is now overridden by your global setting.
- Read your repository's configuration file for settings.  Anything you set here that was already set is now overridden by the repository's setting.
- Apply any `-c key=value` arguments from the command line.  Anything you set here that was already set is now overridden by the command-line setting.

This is particularly useful if you, e.g., do consulting work: you can set your name and email address to your personal settings, then, for each repository on which you're doing consulting work, set your name and email address to whatever the job requires for that repository.

Answer (score 1):

Laziness >> Correctness here. Assuming the server now only has one case variant:

- Push your local branches.
- Blow away your repo (I suggest just renaming the directory so you can recover)
- Start again with a new `git clone`

If you don't want to push everything to the server, you can push to a local bare repository with `git init --bare`.